# Regular expressionJavascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string

So I'm trying to replace the following url with appropriate value from my matchedResult object:

```
var matchedResult={
  "username": "foo",
  "token": "123"
}

var oURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}";
```

I have tried the following:

```
var matchedResult={
  "username": "foo",
  "token": "123"
}

var match,
regex = /#\{(.*?)\}/g,
oURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}";
while (match = regex.exec(oURL)) {
    oURL.replace(match[0], matchedResult[match[1]])
}

console.log(oURL);
```

but still the result is

> "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}"

instead of

> https://graph.facebook.com/foo/posts?access_token=123

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't modify the original string, as JavaScript's strings are immutables, but returns a new String object. Quoting MDN,

> The **`replace()`** method **returns a new string** with some or all matches of a `pattern` replaced by a `replacement`.

So, you need to assign the result of the `replace` to `oURL`, so that the old replacements are still in `oURL`, like this

```
oURL = oURL.replace(match[0], matchedResult[match[1]]);
```

---

**ECMAScript 2015 (ECMAScript 6) way of doing this**

If you are in an environment which supports [ECMA Script 2015's Quasi String literals/Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), then you can simply do

```
`https://graph.facebook.com/${matchedResult.username}/posts?access_token=${matchedResult.token}`
```

**Note:** The backticks at the ends are part of the new syntax.

[Online Demo with Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20matchedResult%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22username%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22token%22%3A%20%22123%22%0A%7D%3B%0Aalert(%60https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2F%24%7BmatchedResult.username%7D%2Fposts%3Faccess_token%3D%24%7BmatchedResult.token%7D%60)%3B)

Comment: Nice answer! Sorry Im new to EC6; do you know whether we can use it in Node.js? How can I use it? Should I require/include something to use their features/syntax? Thanks

Comment: As of now, node.js doesn't support it but io.js does.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the code from

```
oURL.replace(match[0], matchedResult[match[1]])
```

to

```
oURL = oURL.replace(match[0], matchedResult[match[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by using **[replace callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)** method instead of `exec`, so you not need to work with loops, <kbd>Demo</kbd>:

```js
var matchedResult = {
   "username": "foo",
   "token": "123"
};
var oURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}";
oURL = oURL.replace(/#\{([^}]+)\}/g, function(a,b){
   return matchedResult[b] || a
});
alert(oURL)
```